# Проектирование архитектуры игры "шахматы"

Tags: ооп, архитектура, qt, c++

Есть реализация класса `Figure`:

```
#include "figure.h"

    Figure::Figure(QPoint coord,QString name,QRect rect,QString color,QObject *parent) :
        QObject(parent)
    {
        this->name=name;
        this->color=color;
        QPixmap img2("C:/Documents and Settings/Denis/QTProjects/chess/spatial.png");
        this->_img=img2.copy(rect);

    }
    void Figure::isMoveTo(QPoint from,QPoint to)
    {
         //данная функция виртуальная
    }
```

И есть класс `FigureList` (список всех фигур):

```
QList<Figure>
```

При вызовы функции **Figure->isMoveTo(QPoint(1,1),QPoint(1,2))** мы по координатам в списке должны получать тип фигуры,то есть класс Figure должен иметь доступ к `FigureList`.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы сделал по-другому. Это не дело фигуры — знать, где расположены другие фигуры.

Фигура должна уметь ответить на вопрос: может ли она потенциально

- перейти на данное поле?
- перейти на данное поле со взятием?

И какие поля при этом будут пройдены.

(Различие между переходом и взятием актуально для пешек, например.)

А вот уже внешняя по отношению к фигуре логика должна определить, что за фигура стоит на целевом поле, своя/чужая, нет ли на проходимых полях других фигур и т. п.

Обратите внимание на специальный случай взятия на проходе (снимается фигура, не стоящая на целевом поле) и рокировки (двигаются *две* фигуры).

Кстати, на английском шахматная фигура называется [*piece*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_piece), так что я бы переназвал класс.

---

И ещё: я бы разделил *логику фигуры* (определяющую, куда фигура может пойти и каков номер поля, на котором она находится) от *представления фигуры* (определяющего, какая картинка представляет фигуру на экране, и каковы координаты прямоугольника на экране, где она изображается). Это два очевидно разных класса с очевидно разными областями ответственности.

Comment: Есть ли смысл добавления класса **Player**,у которого будут функции
**takeFigure(взятие фигуры перед ходом)** и **Move(Figure,from,to)-собсвенно ход**.И собсвенно Player(игрок) видит есть ли там фигура или нет.Что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: Интересно, takeFigure() это что, графика с пальцами тянущимися к фигуре? (шутка)

Что отличного от Move() должен этот метод делать?

--

А вообще, подумайте о классе Board, представляющим игру в целом. Ведь Вам нужно как-то оценивать ценность (извиняюсь за тавтологию) и незанятых фигурами полей, в зависимости от текущей позиции на доске.

Comment: насчет **takeFigure()**-вы правы

Comment: Как я понимаю-Шахматная доска(Board)-это набор клеток(экземпляры класса Cell),а вот Game(Игра)-это шахматная доска и фигуры.

Comment: Я бы сделал отдельный класс `GameRules` (инкапсулирующий, понятно, правила игры), который бы отвечал на вопросы:

* Какие ходы возможны для данной фигуры по правилам?
   * Возможен ли данный ход?
* Каков результат возможного хода? (взятие? шах? мат? возможность превращения пешки?)

Класс `Player` должен либо перебрать возможные ходы и руководствуясь внутренней стратегией, выбрать из них наилучший, либо получить ход от пользователя и проверить его на возможность.

Comment: Говоря о Board, я имею в виду вещь несколько иную, чем просто матрица из 64 клеток (хотя, 64 клетки, безусловно, одна из ее частей). Возможно ее надо назвать CurrentPosition. Одним из ее элементов является числовая оценка позиции.

Вся игра состоит в переборах таких Board (обычно улучшающих текущую оценку), которые ведут к мату.

@Denis Makarenko, вообще, на этапе проектирования попробуйте отвлечься от классов в смысле их реализации в С++, смотрите не объекты шире.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1)

Функция isMoveTo перемещается в `FigureList`. Это решает часть проблем. Конечно, придется много переписать.

Вариант 2)

Создается специальный класс, который наследует `FigureList`. У каждого `Figure` есть ссылка на этот специальный класс. Так как `Figure` создается классом FigureList, то никто не мешает ему передать `this` - то есть ссылку на себя. Это конечно сделает циклические ссылки, но при правильном подходе будет нормально. (при желании можно прикрутить `smart_pointer` + `weak_pointer`).